# how to removed selected text, currently is double click removed the whole textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Basic Drag and Drop</title>
<style>
#drop {
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px dashed #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  clear: left;
}
p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
#triangle {

  background: url(images/triangle.jpg) no-repeat;
}
#square {
  background: url(images/square.gif) no-repeat;
}
#circle {
  background: url(images/circle.jpg) no-repeat;
}
#red {
  background: url(images/red.jpg) no-repeat;
}
#yellow {
  background: url(images/yellow.jpg) no-repeat;
}
#green {
  background: url(images/green.jpg) no-repeat;
}
.drag {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  float: left;
  -khtml-user-drag: element;
  margin: 10px;
}
</style>
<script>
var addEvent = (function () {
  if (document.addEventListener) {
    return function (el, type, fn) {
      if (el && el.nodeName || el === window) {
        el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
      } else if (el && el.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
          addEvent(el[i], type, fn);
        }
      }
    };
  } else {
    return function (el, type, fn) {
      if (el && el.nodeName || el === window) {
        el.attachEvent('on' + type, function () { return fn.call(el, window.event); });
      } else if (el && el.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
          addEvent(el[i], type, fn);
        }
      }
    };
  }
})();

(function () {

var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.id = "view-source"

// private scope to avoid conflicts with demos
addEvent(window, 'click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.hash == '#view-source') {
    // event.preventDefault();
    if (!document.getElementById('view-source')) {
      // pre.innerHTML = ('<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n' + document.documentElement.innerHTML + '\n</html>').replace(/[<>]/g, function (m) { return {'<':'&lt;','>':'&gt;'}[m]});
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      // original source - rather than rendered source
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          pre.innerHTML = this.responseText.replace(/[<>]/g, function (m) { return {'<':'&lt;','>':'&gt;'}[m]});
          prettyPrint();
        }
      };

      document.body.appendChild(pre);
      // really need to be sync? - I like to think so
      xhr.open("GET", window.location, true);
      xhr.send();
    }
    document.body.className = 'view-source';

    var sourceTimer = setInterval(function () {
      if (window.location.hash != '#view-source') {
        clearInterval(sourceTimer);
        document.body.className = '';
      }
    }, 200);
  }


});

})();
</script>

<style id="jsbin-css">

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="drag" id="triangle" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="drag" id="square" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="drag" id="circle" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="drag" id="red" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="drag" id="yellow" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="drag" id="green" draggable="true"></div>

  <div id="drop"></div>
<script>
function cancel(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return false;
}

var dragItems = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable=true]');

for (var i = 0; i < dragItems.length; i++) {
  addEvent(dragItems[i], 'dragstart', function (event) {
    // store the ID of the element, and collect it on the drop later on
    event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id);




  });
}


var drop = document.querySelector('#drop');

// Tells the browser that we *can* drop on this target
addEvent(drop, 'dragover', cancel);
addEvent(drop, 'dragenter', cancel);
addEvent(drop, 'drop', function (e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); // stops the browser from redirecting off to the text.
 this.innerHTML += '<p>' + e.dataTransfer.getData('Text') + '</p>';

  return false;
});
</script>
<script>
document.getElementById('drop').ondblclick = function(){
this.innerHTML="";//remove your text here
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in the line of below is to removed the whole box called drop name. but i want to removed the selected text that i added inside only. others text, i still want it to remain stay inside the  drop box.Is it need to be code one by one for the data drop inside or how is going to work on? Please help me... thanks so much.

```
document.getElementById('drop').ondblclick = function(){
    this.innerHTML="";//remove your text here
    };
```

Comment: Question not clear. Put HTML as well. What exactly do you need?

Comment: Make a fiddle for this..

Comment: its is a drag and drop function... i have a few picture, once you drag on one picture to the box, the box will have the text that have declared on picture means, after i drag and drop the picture, displayed text that have in the box, i want to delete the selected text only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove / manipulate selected text, then look at the Selection and Range object API's [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getSelection), but bear in mind these may still be non-standard API's

There is a [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WaawN/1/) example here which will report the selected  range and also remove the selected text:

```
document.getElementById("drop").ondblclick = function() {
    var sel = window.getSelection(),
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0),
        text = this.innerHTML,
        toRemove,
        editedText;
    //console.log("sel ", sel, " range ", range);

    toRemove = text.substring(range.startOffset,range.endOffset);
    editedText = text.slice(0, range.startOffset) + text.slice(range.endOffset);

    console.log("toRemove ", toRemove);
    console.log("editedText ", editedText);
}
```

Bear in mind that double-clicking on an area of text may vary in behaviour - if I double click text in Chrome, it only selects a single word.